# How to stop all threads if anyone fails in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a flat file say a csv file of 50mb that contains a structured data, and I need read them and then need to push into a db say MySQL. One way to do is splitting file into multiple and then processing in parallel using executors. This is okie. Now the second use case if any one data is incorrect, I need to stop processing of all the threads which means if any one data found in csv is incorrect we should not process the transaction. I need idea for second part.

Thanks,
RK

Comment: Could you do something like an `AtomicBoolean stillAlive` that they all share, and periodically check? Then anyone can just set it to false, and the other threads will soon read that and know to stop.

Comment: 50mb seems on the small side. Surprised you’d have to mess with threads for this. Can’t MySQL read in a csv without using jdbc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 50MB, you'd be over complicating this design by adding multiple threads. Flat file or structured data like JSON can be ripped through with a single thread in seconds if not faster. Spinning up multiple threads for 50MB of data is overkill. On a number of occasions, I've handled the same use case with 400+ MB of JSON or CSV data with single thread.

You also have to consider that you are writing to a single DB, in which case multiple threads are going to complicate things as you have multiple transactions. Taking your CSV example, it sounds like you intend for each thread to be responsible for reading one or more lines and write it to the DB? In which case, each thread is operating in its own JDBC transaction. Thus, if you stop all threads, you're going to end up with partially written data in the DB as some threads may have completed work already and resulted in a completed transaction. Since each thread is operating independently, you don't have the opportunity to rollback all the already committed transactions for the completed threads.

If you're still committed to parallelization for 50MB of data, consider making 2 passes:

1. To read and validate the data and generate the appropriate SQL insert statements
2. If all threads are successful, execute the generated SQL file

This would do what you want and you guarantee that you file completely if there's a validation error before any data is written to the DB. Second, it ensures that the data can be written to the DB atomically. To do what you want, you'd want to use something like a [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) or some other type of synchronizer in the `java.util.concurrent` package.

There are also plenty of frameworks out there that make this stuff easier and handle error cases and reusability of jobs. [Spring Batch](https://spring.io/projects/spring-batch) is one such tool and there are several more.

Comment: Makes sense Ryan.

Answer (score 0):

Do use `ThreadGroup`.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    final ThreadGroup group = new ThreadGroup("Thread Group");

    new Thread(group, () -> {
        // payload
        group.interrupt();
    }).start();

    new Thread(group, () -> {
        // payload
        group.interrupt();
    }).start();
}
```